# Prove: if $m \in n$ then $m^+ \subseteq n$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, peano-axioms

The following is exercise 5(d), section 6.2, from *A book of set theory*, by Charles Pinter (pg. 122).

> **5.** Prove the following, where $m, n, p \in \omega$.
>
> **d)** If $m \in n$, then $m^+ \subseteq n$.

These are the relevant definition and results, quoted from the same book:

> **6.2 Theorem** For each $n \in \omega$, $n^+ \neq 0$.

> **6.4 Lemma** Let $m$ and $n$ be natural numbers; if $m \in n^+$, then $m \in n$ or $m = n$.

> **6.1 Definition** By the *set of the natural numbers* we mean the intersection of all the successor sets. The set of the natural numbers is designated by the symbol $\omega$; every element of $\omega$ is called a *natural number*.

**Attempted proof:**

Suppose  $m^{+} \nsubseteq n$ then $n \in m$ and so $n \subseteq m$ ,but $m \subseteq m^{+}$ and so $n \subseteq m^{+}$.

But by 6.4 $m \in n$, then (because $n$ is transitive) $m \subseteq n$; and then $m \subseteq n^{+}$.

So we have two successors for $m$ by 6.4 (contradiction, since we must have $m \in n$).

Hence $S(m) \subseteq n$.

Comment: Hi Eudoxus, welcome. While your question is legible in its current form, it is considered good practice to use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format questions. It would also help if you would clearly define your notation (for example, what is $S(n)$, and what is $\omega$?) for those who do not have access to the book you mention.

Comment: See [von Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#von_Neumann_ordinals): "$S(n) = n \cup \{ n \}$ for every set $n$."

Comment: S(n) is the successor of n

Comment: Are you sure about the statement of the problem ? $1 \in 2$ but $2 \notin 2$.

Comment: Doh! Found the mistake and corrected it and using “+” notation Hope it is more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $m^+=m\cup\{m\}$.

Assuming $m\in n$, you want to show that $m^+\subseteq n$, which means that for any $x$ you have $$x\in m^+ \qquad\implies x\subseteq n.$$

If $x\in m^+=m\cup\{m\}$, then we have two possibilities:

- If $x=m$ we immediately get $x\in $.
- If $x\in m$ and $m\in n$, we get that $x\in n$ from the fact that $n$ is transitive (Lemma 6.6).

Notice that there are two equivalent definitions of [transitive sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set). The one we used here is stated in this book in the first exercise in this section.